# Proofs using Mathematical logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

While going through many proofs in graph theory, I noticed that for proof of statement like

> a if and only  if b

we need to prove

$a \rightarrow b$ and  $b \rightarrow a$.

We  know

$$  a\rightarrow b  ={a}'+b$$

and

$$b\rightarrow a  ={b}'+a $$

also

$${a}'\rightarrow {b}'=a''+b'=a+b'=b\rightarrow a$$

So in proof we can only prove $a\rightarrow b$

and ${a}'\rightarrow {b}'$

No need of proving $b\rightarrow a$

Am i correct ?please help me out ..!!!

Comment: $a'\to b' \equiv b\to a$.  So indeed, yes, in proving $a'\to b'$, you will have proved its equivalent, (it contrapositive): $b\to a$

Comment: Assuming $a'$ means not $a$, I don't know what you mean by "no need of proving $b\to a$".  $a'\to b'$ is *equivalent* to $b\to a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Proving the contrapositive is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it:

If you prove the following two statements:
$\begin{align} 
a &\implies b \\
 \text{not }a &\implies \text{not }b
\end{align}$

... you have shown that $a$ and $b$ are either both true or both false; the two statements are in lockstep. $a \mathord\iff b$.